# Script on parent site not working on child site: $.Deferred is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, deferred, slick.js

I have a website that is built off a parent site, and needs to be as identical as possible. My clients have a process through which they grab all the scripts and css files of the parent site and use them to create the child. For one of these websites though, I am getting an error in the main javascript file that is not happening on the parent site.

Here are the two websites:

[parent site](http://www.wma.us/support-wma/ways-to-give/other-ways-to-give)

[child site](http://wma2.stage.pgdonors.org/)

The main issue is that the carousel at the top of the page (I believe it's using slickslider) is not getting initialized on the child site. I am not sure if this is because of the Javascript errors, and if you can figure out the reason why it's not working I will be super grateful as that is the main issue at hand. That said, I'm assuming right now that my problem is the javascript error in main.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: l.Deferred is not a function
```

Again, there are no errors on the parent site, but l.Deferred breaks on the child site. Why isn't it working?

I tried wrapping l in jQuery -- $(l).Deferred -- but when I did this it seemed to cause a loop, where the page would spend several minutes trying to load before timing out and crashing.

If you can tell me why the slider on my child site isn't working, or at the very least why l.Deferred is breaking, that would be a huge help.

EDIT: Update to use the correct version of jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>jq11 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script src="/sites/all/themes/wma2/js/main.js"></script>

(function($){
    window.matchMedia || (window.matchMedia = function(){....
})(jq11);
```

UPDATE: I checked the console and $.fn.jQuery is using the jquery 1.11.2 at the point when it says l.Deferred is not a function

I also tried wrapping l in the correct jquery:

```
jq11(l).Deferred
```

but when I do that the page gets stuck in a loop and crashes after trying to load for several minutes.

Comment: Looks like you have a syntax error in the one JS file

Comment: l in this case actually looks like it refers to jQuery itself, so jq11(l).Deferred would be like doing jq11(jQuery).Deferred which causes all sorts of weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what "process through which they grab all the scripts and css files of the parent site and use them to create the child" means, but the client page is at least at some point loading jQuery 1.4.4 (check the first of the last 3 included scripts in the head).

$.Deferred wasn't introduced until jQuery 1.5, https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/ so trying to run anything using 1.4.4 will throw an error because that function, indeed, doesn't exist there.

One of the last scripts on the page loads *another* entire copy of jQuery, and THAT one, 1.11, does support Deferreds.  But it's almost the last thing to run on the page, so almost no code uses it.  So you have an old jQuery, then code that tries to use a method in a newer jQuery, and then finally a newer jQuery.  That's why jQuery and $ aren't even assigned to the same thing, as you can confirm in the console:

jQuery.fn.jquery: "1.4.4"

$.fn.jquery: "1.11.2"

It's possible that you have code that uses old 1.4.4 syntax, so you may not be able to replace it, but it's probably best, if you do need both versions, to wrap all your code explicitly in an IIFE

```
(function($){ 
  /* code using $, which maps to whatever is specified at the end*/   
})(jQuery);
```

that specifies which of the two you mean to use.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! So, I wrapped the entire main.js script in (function($){})(jQuery) but I don't think I did it right. I'm now getting the error  $(...).on is not a function. What am I missing? The script on the child page is updated if you want to check it.

Comment: Also, how were you able to tell which version it was using?

Comment: Just entering jQuery.fn.jquery or $.fn.jquery directly into the console.  The error you're getting now is the same problem basically: $.fn.on is not defined in jQuery 1.4.4 but whatever jQuery you piped into the IIFE that wrapped that usage of $(...).on was still 1.4.4, not 1.11.2

Comment: In this case, your IIFE's that are _below_ the 1.11.2 script should probably use (function($){  })(jq11) or even (function($){  })($) as weird as that sounds.  Both map to a version that support $.Deferred and $.fn.on, but the noConflict is handing back control of "jQuery" itself to the 1.4.4 version.

    $.fn.jquery
    "1.11.2"
    jQuery.fn.jquery
    "1.4.4"
    jq11.fn.jquery
    "1.11.3"

Comment: I edited my original post to show my latest changes. I added a new reference to jquery 1.11 above the main.js script, used noConflict and specified the version in the (function($)) wrap, but it still thinks l.Deferred is not a function.